# How to update a SQL column that has key-value pairs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL column called `pairs` that consists of key value pairs like this:

```
{"fr":"true","it":"false","lastValue":"false"}
```

I want to update `lastValue` to true. If `lastValue` doesn't exist, I want to add it to the column. I saw the concat function which lets me append it to the column like this:

```
set pairs = concat(substring(pairs, 1, char_length(pairs) - 1), ',"lastValue":"', 'true',"'}')
```

But if the value already exists, I want to update the existing value. If it doesn't exist, I want to concatenate it. Is there a way to do that in SQL?

Comment: Storing multiple values in a column is almost always a sign of a poor database design. This is just the first of many problems you will have with such a table.

Comment: Calling the multiple values JSON doesn't change it from a poor design into a good design.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the memo saying that the fundamental rules of database design had been superseded by a data-interchange format. Good to know. But I wonder why I keep seeing people having the same problems with storing multiple values in json that they've always had with storing multiple values in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON data type and JSON_SET

```
update t set pairs = JSON_SET(pairs, "$.lastValue", "true") 
Where pairs->>'$.lastValue' = '' ;
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8758a307739c5badec6eacc6b7f99755)